# Drupal 7 - How to loop foreach in multiple value in custom view

Tags: views, entities

I'm customizing a view (in views-view--myview.tpl.php) based on a node which has a field with multiple value (field_galerie_image).

I'm trying to list in a foreach loop that particular field, and I am wondering how to write it down.

In the following code, I can access a value with `$vue->_field_data["nid"]["entity"]->field_galerie_image['und'][0]["filename"];` but I need to loop through it.

```
$vue->_field_data["nid"]["entity"]->field_galerie_image['und'][1]["filename"];
$vue->_field_data["nid"]["entity"]->field_galerie_image['und'][2]["filename"];
```

The code I am using is the following one.

```
<?php foreach ($view->result as $id => $vue): ?>
  <?php if($vue): ?>  
    <?php print $vue->nid; ?>
    <?php print $vue->node_title; ?>

    <?php print $vue->_field_data["nid"]["entity"]->field_galerie_image['und'][0]["filename"]; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found it out; the correct code is the following one.

```
<?php foreach ($view->result as $id => $vue): ?>
  <?php if($vue): ?>  
    <?php print $vue->nid; ?>
    <?php print $vue->node_title; ?>

    <?php foreach ($vue->_field_data["nid"]["entity"]->field_galerie_image['und'] as $val): ?>
      <?php print $val['filename']; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```